# How can I append the store_id of the current v-for element to this.apiUrl? Thanks

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

```
<div v-for="store in order_stores">
    <order-products-table :order_url="this.apiUrl"></order-products-table>
</div>
```

I want to append the `store_id` of current element to `this.apiUrl`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can write it as simple JavaScript.

```
<order-products-table :order_url="this.apiUrl + store.store_id"/>
```

Any time you have a binding (the colon), treat the inside code like normal JavaScript.